# ruby sub when replacement string starts with \0

Tags: ruby, string, backreference

In ruby, sub does not allow to replace a string by another one starting with '\0'.

```
'a'.sub('a','\\0b')
```

Returns:

```
'ab'
```

The doc says that \0 is interpreted as a backreference, but as the first parameter is not a Regexp, I don't understand why it works like that.

Comment: In other words, how to be sure that s.sub('a', r) works as expected when r is a string with an unknown content?

Comment: Like starts with *backslash zero* or starts with *literal zero*?

Comment: @tadman: Backslash zero

Answer (score 2):

If you want your second argument to be interpreted as a plain String you can escape it like:

```
'a'.sub('a', Regexp.escape('\0b'))
```

or

```
'a'.sub('a', '\\\0b')
```

both returns:

```
"\\0b"
```

Explanation about this behaviour can be found in [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-sub)

`sub(pattern, replacement) → new_str`

> The pattern is typically a Regexp; if given as a String, any regular
>   expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally,
>   e.g. '\d' will match a backslash followed by 'd', instead of a digit.
>
> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched
>   text. **It may contain back-references to the pattern's capture groups
>   of the form `"\d"`, where d is a group number**, or `"\k<n>"`, where n is a
>   group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must
>   be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement
>   the special match variables, such as $&, will not refer to the current
>   match. If replacement is a String that looks like a pattern's capture
>   group but is actually not a pattern capture group e.g. "\'", then it
>   will have to be preceded by two backslashes like so "\'".

Comment: Ok, so sub(s,Regexp.escape(r)) is the right way to replace a string in another. Not sure that everybody knowns that!!! Thanks.